# How can I make my AR application be more steady with the markers?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using vuforia AR on Unity, My app should produce a 3D character for each marker it reads which it does, but it looks really bad and the 3D model keeps moving away from the marker ... Any idea how to make it steady on the marker?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your problem? Also, any C# code you are using to generate the models.